# Rails: Performance benchmarking using RSPec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rspec, benchmarking

I'm just coming across to RSpec from rake:test, and I'm struggling to find any equivalent to rake test:benchmark and/or rake test:profile.

So, what do most rspec folks use for performance testing? I've found --profile, which spits back the ten slowest tests, but I was hoping for something a little more comprehensive.

Cheers...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Diaspora project took an interesting approach to performance testing with rspec -- tests that say "this method should be fast / take less than N ms"

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/a6f8b2c14ed7ec13f2ecd113ae809a072814ab50/spec/controllers/aspects_controller_spec.rb#L92

Different than the typical approach but implementable without any half-baked rspec plugins

Comment: link is broken :( Perhaps gist could be a better long-lasting answer

Comment: @user80805 Just click into the commit history and find the old code.  That is what I did.

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/a6f8b2c14ed7ec13f2ecd113ae809a072814ab50/spec/controllers/aspects_controller_spec.rb#L92

Comment: They removed it. I wonder what [the actual reason was](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/commit/33ba00377e395cf06f48b6f8b5e162230191957e#comments). I can think of some myself like - inconsistent results between runs and machines is the deal breaker perhaps, but there are some advantages of integrating this inside testing process as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is [rspec-benchmark](https://github.com/piotrmurach/rspec-benchmark) ruby gem which allows to test the performance in the clean and readable way:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_under(0.01).sec
```

You can also specify the number of times to run your code to measure performance:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_under(0.01).and_sample(10)
```